# Microsoft SQL report server authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, reporting-services

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to bypass the standard windows authentication used to access published reports in the report website front end.

I know about the different authentication methods, RSWindowsNegotiate,  RSWindowsKerberos, RSWindowsNTLM and RSWindowsBasic. I also know there is the custom authentication option where I have to go and create my own Login ASP.net page.

The issue is I am trying to set up a role for a user to limit what the user can see and do in the front end without adding another user to the windows active directory.

So the user must be able to log in with their own username and password and only be able to view what their permissions are set to.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Creating a new Windows user **IS** the simple way of doing this!

Comment: Unfortunately due to licensing I am limited to 2 users. So I cant create a new user.

Comment: What you're describing is "Multiplexing", and you still need to license those users... http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/E/48E9A4EB-125A-49CB-9644-169B82C45611/SQL2008R2_QRG_2011.pdf

Comment: Is there no other way to create a new user without creating a user in the windows active directory?

Answer (score 0):

I would not call it a simple way, but there is a way to do this. Check out this article on SQLServerCentral: [How to Setup Report Parameters to Default Based On User Credentials](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+%28SSRS%29/72897/)

It describes the following steps to implement this:

1. create a report users table in your sql server database
2. create a UserID parameter
3. adapt your report queries to identify the user and use that
   information to show only permitted data

Comment: Interesting article but I don't think it is entirely relevant. I need a way to add authentication to the report server front end that will be available to the client on the web. I need to add roles to the clients credentials so that they have limited access.

Comment: @Jean-LouisKroon: ah, I see. I'll leave this answer around for the time being, hope someone else can give you a more helpful one!